# Parent directory headers using Arduino

Tags: header, include, arduino

I have a few headers and source files which I want to be common between two sketches (as they are communication interfaces) but I can't include them in my sketches: this very arguable system of tabs refuses to find them when I use relative paths.

Example:

```
Project
-interface.h
-interface.cpp
-sketch1
--sketch1.ino
-sketch2
--sketch2.ino
```

I would like to do:

```
#include "../interface.h"
```

Without making a library out of it and putting it elsewhere (so as not to have to move around files when they are handed out to somebody else).

Thank you for your help (I'm growing mad over here ),

Mister Mystère

P.S: Version is 1.0.5 on Windows

Comment: I've already looked at several posts online which were about this problem and it was very often a matter of "just restart and the tabs should appear automatically"... Well they don't. I have also tried the backslash without success.

Comment: What if you just `#include "interface.h"` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't work either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bad news is you probably have to place interface.h/c in a library folder.  The good news is that it is **not** that difficult.  Simply create a folder named "interface" as a peer to other library folders and cut/paste `interface.h/c` into that folder.

Finally, after creating the new folder/lib you will need to completely exit Arduino's IDE and restart it, before you can select a new "interface" lib for your sketch.

Comment: Thanks, when I heard library in my head it was in the proper way, with compilation or a statically or dynamically linked library. This is not as flexible as what I could do without Arduino, but it is not that much of a hassle.

Comment: @MisterMystère, thank-you for the question.  I like those little Arduino boards.

Comment: @JackCColeman this answer is from 2 years ago, and unfortunately it doesn't work anymore. How do I include the parent .h file/parent library?

Answer (score 0):

Create symbolic links to all of the required files.

**Linux**

```
ln -s sourcefile targetfile
```

**Windows**

```
mklink targetfile sourcefile
```